# Finding All Combinations

Tags: combinations

**Question**

Consider the following prices on balls:

\begin{alignat}{2}
  &\text{Red (R):}   &       15&\\
  &\text{Green (B):} &        6&\\
  &\text{Blue (G):}  &\qquad  8&
\end{alignat}

**Question**

Is there an "elegant" way of finding all the possible ways of bying balls for a total sum of $90$?

**My own approach**

By a brute force search, I have found the following possibilities, but can I somehow find this in a more "elegant" way?

\begin{alignat}{3}
  (0\,&\text{R},{} & 3\,&\text{G},{} &9\,&\text{B})\\
  (0\,&\text{R},   & 7\,&\text{G},   &6\,&\text{B})\\
  (0\,&\text{R},   &11\,&\text{G},   &3\,&\text{B})\\
  (0\,&\text{R},   &15\,&\text{G},   &0\,&\text{B})\\
  (2\,&\text{R},   &10\,&\text{G},   &0\,&\text{B})\\
  (2\,&\text{R},   & 2\,&\text{G},   &6\,&\text{B})\\
  (2\,&\text{R},   & 6\,&\text{G},   &4\,&\text{B})\\
  (4\,&\text{R},   & 1\,&\text{G},   &3\,&\text{B})\\
  (4\,&\text{R},   & 5\,&\text{G},   &0\,&\text{B})\\
  (6\,&\text{R},   & 0\,&\text{G},   &0\,&\text{B})
\end{alignat}

**Update**

$(2\,\text{R},{} 6\,\text{G},{} 4\,\text{B}) \to (2\,\text{R},{} 6\,\text{G},{} 3\,\text{B})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer $(2,6,4)$ is incorrect.

Idk what method you have adopted, here is one systematic approach that you could using simple [Diophantine equations](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/MATH_2150%3A_Higher_Arithmetic/5%3A_Diophantine_Equations/5.1%3A_Linear_Diophantine_Equations).

Firstly reduce $15r + 6b + 8g = 90$ to $5r +2b + {\frac8 3}g = 30$.

So $g$ can only be from $0, 3,6,9$ with the corresponding reduced values of the totals being $30$, $22$, $14$, and $6$.

For each of these totals, we can form Diaphontine equations in two variables, eg for the total of $30$.

$5r + 2b = 30,\, b = 15 - \frac 5 2 r$

which immediately yields $(r,b,g)$ values of $(0,15,0), (2,10,0), (4,5,0)$ and $(6,0,0)$.

Similarly for the other three cases, you get the equations

$b = 11 - \frac5 2r,\quad b = 7 - \frac5 2r,\quad b = 3 - \frac5 2 r$

which you can enumerate similarly.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution is actually more "natural" to me, så I'll accept this answer, but both of them are really good.

Comment: Glad to be of help !

Answer (score 5):

We are looking for values $r,g,b$ such that
$$15r +6g + 8b = 90.$$
Immediately note that since $15$ is odd, $r$ must be even, let $r = 2R$. Then we want

$$30R + 6g + 8b = 90.$$

Next, observe that $6|\;30R,\;6g,\;90 \implies 6|8b,$ so $b$ must be a multiple of 3, let $b=3B$, now we want

$$30R + 6g + 24B = 90$$

$$\iff 5R + g + 4B = 15$$

Now I would consider the cases $R=0,1,2,3$, there is still some case by case work to do but perhaps it's easier.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll take a look at your answer later today.

Comment: so cool!!!!!!!!!!!!